# PHPChart how to add data label in stack bar chart?

Tags: php, charts

I'm using PHPChart for chart creation, i have problem in adding data label on series of stack bar chart. something like bellow:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
$line1 = array(4, 2, 9, 16);
    $line2 = array(3, 7, 6.25, 3.125);
    $pc = new C_PhpChartX(array($line1,$line2),'stackChart'.$chartId);
    $pc->add_plugins(array('canvasTextRenderer'));
    $pc->set_title(array('text'=> $config['title']));
    $pc->set_stack_series(true);
    $pc->set_animate(true);
    $pc->set_legend(
        array(
            'renderer' => 'plugin::EnhancedLegendRenderer',
            'show'=>true,
            'location' => 'e',
            'placement' => 'outside',
            'yoffset' => 30,
            'rendererOptions' => array('numberRows'=>2)
        )
    );
    $pc->set_series_default(
        array(
            'renderer'=> 'plugin::BarRenderer',
            'rendererOptions'=> array('barPadding'=>6,'barMargin'=>40),
            'shadow' => true
        ));
    foreach($seriesKeys as $k => $v){
        $pc->add_series(array('label' => $config['series'][$v]));
    }
    //$pc->add_series(array('label'=>'1st Qtr'));
    //$pc->add_series(array('label'=>'2nd Qtr'));

    $pc->set_xaxes(array(
        'xaxis'=>array(
            'renderer'=>'plugin::CategoryAxisRenderer',
            'ticks'   => $config['ticks'],
            'label'   => $config['label']
        )
    ));
    $pc->set_yaxes(array(
        'yaxis' => array(
            'borderWidth'=>0,
            'borderColor'=>'#ffffff',
            'autoscale'=>true,
            'labelRenderer'=>'plugin::CanvasAxisLabelRenderer',
            'label'=>'Number of assignee')
    ));
    $pc->draw();
```

But above code draw a chart like the chart i have uploaded except data label that is 1,2,3 or any digit that should be displayed(it means count of present and absent participants should be displayed on series)

Comment: Where's your code? What do you need?

Comment: I have found the solution only add this `$pc->add_plugins(array('pointLabels','canvasTextRenderer'),true);`